# Tomcat's javax.servlet and resolving dependencies with Apache Ivy problem

Tags: spring, tomcat, ivy

I'm using Apache Ivy with Spring based project. I use [Spring Enterprise Bundle Repository](http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/) mostly. I run my project on Tomcat 7. The problem is that some dependencies, e.g. TestNG also download javax.servlet.jar and javax.servlet.jsp.jar, which interfere with the Tomcat's original ones. How do I deal with that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either exclude specific dependencies from your dependency declaration or simply tell Ivy not to resolve transitive dependencies at all. Here are two examples:

**Explicit exclusion:**

```
<dependencies>  
   <dependency org="org.testng" name="testng" rev="5.8">
       <exclude org="javax.servlet" name="servlet-api" /> 
       <exclude org="javax.servlet" name="jsp-api" />
   </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**Exclude all transitive dependencies:**

```
<dependency org="org.testng" name="testng" rev="5.8" transitive="false" />
```